# Passing Argument from Java to Sql

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I've worked with sqlplus and Java but never together until now. I'm having difficulty in getting a command line argument into sql to return a regular expression-specific list of users. My if statement and error is below. I believe the program is actually searching the list of users for "^A". Any tips on resolving this would be greatly appreciated.

```
else if (num == 1 && !args[0].equals("-n"))
{
     String cmd = "select * from all_users where regexp_like(username, " + args[0] + ", 'i') order by username";
     System.out.println(cmd);
     String users[] = ora.doSql(cmd);
     for (String u: users)
         System.out.println(u);
 }
```

My results:

```
java ShowUsers ^A
select * from all_users where regexp_like(username, ^A, 'i') order by username
select * from all_users where regexp_like(username, ^A, 'i') order by username
                                                *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00936: missing expression
```

Comment: https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: `^A` should be surrounded by quotes

Comment: Michelle, there's a great online tutorial for prepared statements at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html and I think it would be worthwhile for you to try to rewrite your code in the way that this tutorial describes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quotes are missing inside `refexp_like`. Try the following:

```
else if (num == 1 && !args[0].equals("-n"))
{
     String cmd = "select * from all_users where regexp_like(username, '" + args[0] + "', 'i') order by username";
     System.out.println(cmd);
     String users[] = ora.doSql(cmd);
     for (String u: users)
         System.out.println(u);
 }
```

However, as mentioned by all others, this is considered a bad practice and your code will be prone to [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).
So you should really use prepared statements instead.

Answer (score 2):

You should never use string concatenation for JDBC queries as they are vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Instead you should use [prepared statements](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-statements.htm).

If you have to use String concatenation you can follow whatever @vkp mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Perhaps OP is working on building some kind of SQL console; in which case vulnerability to SQL injection is kind of a requirement.  It seems clear to me that code that displays a list of users is unlikely to be code that can be run by "Jo User on the Internet".

Comment: Thank you. I definitely came across prepared statements, but we are only supposed to use knowledge we have learned in class thus far - which of course just started. Adding the single quotation marks, as suggested by Plirkee, worked perfectly.